# Rust Dedicated server - Server crashes after startup

Tags: rust

So I've been running a dedicated Rust server for some time, with no issue. I had created a couple different worlds (different seeds with different server identities) and switching between them with no problem. There was a Rust client update today, so I used the steamcmd.exe and app_update as usual, and it said it was successful. However now when I try to load any world (even a brand new one) I get this:

```
Navmesh Build took 50.18 seconds
Map Spawned 309 entities
Couldn't load server/MyServer/proceduralmap.4000.123456.147.sav - file doesn't exist
Missing EnvSync - creating
Missing CommunityEntity - creating
Missing ResourceDepositManager - creating
Initializing 27541 entity links
Initializing 234 stability supports
Facepunch.Steamworks Unity: WindowsPlayer
Facepunch.Steamworks Os: Windows
Facepunch.Steamworks Arch: x64
Couldn't initialize Steam Server (0)
eac_server.dll [x64] :: hModule: 00007FFF98750000 dwReason: 1 lpvReserved: 0
Server startup complete

E:\SteamGames\rust_server>
```

I know the sav file not existing is just an artifact of this being a new server, so I'm not worried about that. I've seen from other posts that apparently the eac_server.dll line is okay, people get spammed with that on the console and the server still works, but I never used to get that message before when it worked. Steam just shuts the server down immediately after the `Server startup complete` message.

If it matters, here is my started line:

```
RustDedicated.exe -batchmode +server.port 28015 +server.level "Procedural 
Map" +server.seed 123456 +server.worldsize 4000 +server.maxplayers 10  
+server.hostname "My Rust Server" +server.description "My Rust server" 
+server.identity "MyServer"
```

(broken into multiple lines here just for visibility, single line in the startup file)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the resolution for this was to delete the game/server directory and reinstall Rust Dedicated Server. It seems this must be done every update, even though the app_update appears to be successful.